# How to find apex class included in scheduled apex job

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code, job-scheduling, salesforce-communities

[image]

how to find the apex class in this scheduled apex record.its not showing the apex class , then I try this in apex jobs section but it's  also not showing this job

Please give me solution for that . How do I found that scheduled apex class according to that scheduled job

Answer (score 0):

- Go to apex jobs from setup
- Select the Scheduled Job and click on Edit the you will have second input box which has the apex class selected